# Changing the output of a callback depending on a button in python dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using Python dash and have a callback that updates every 1000 ms and outputs a dummy value (say the number of times the callback has run).

I want to change the output value of the callback when I press a button.

[image: Button pressed]

I found 2 options:

1. using 2 callbacks
2. using a hidden-div

```
# Using 2 callbacks
from dash import dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=1000),  
        html.Button("Press", id="button"), 
        html.Div(id="output")  
    ]
)
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [Input("interval", "n_intervals")],
    [State("button", "n_clicks")]
)
def update_output(n_intervals, n_clicks):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button not pressed"
    if n_clicks != 0:
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button pressed"

@app.callback(
    Output("button", "n_clicks"),
    [Input("output", "children")]
)
def reset_button(n):
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

```
# Using a hidden div
from dash import dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, callback_context

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=1000),  
        html.Button("Press", id="button"),  
        html.Div(id="output"),  
        html.Div(id="hidden-div", style={"display": "none"}, children="0")  
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [Output("output", "children"), Output("hidden-div", "children")],
    [Input("interval", "n_intervals"), Input("button", "n_clicks")],
    [State("hidden-div", "children")] 
)
def update_output(n_intervals, n_clicks, hidden_clicks):
    ctx = callback_context
    if ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"] == "button.n_clicks":
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button pressed", hidden_clicks
    else:
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button not pressed", hidden_clicks

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

What is the best solution ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to AndreVale69's answer, the code below works nicely

```
from dash import dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, ctx

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=1000),  
        html.Button("Press", id="button"),  
        html.Div(id="output"),  
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [Input("interval", "n_intervals"), 
     Input("button", "n_clicks")]
)
def update_output(n_intervals, n_clicks):
    if (ctx.triggered_id == 'interval' or n_intervals == None):
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button not pressed"
    return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button pressed"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to choose, I'd say the first because it's easier to read than the second.
But the idea of the second one isn't so bad. In fact, I'd like to suggest an alternative.
There is a property of ctx (called trigger_id) which is a value (string) of who triggered the callback ([official documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/determining-which-callback-input-changed)). So I'd rewrite the code as follows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [Input("interval", "n_intervals"), 
     Input("button", "n_clicks")]
)
def update_output(n_intervals, n_clicks):
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'interval':
        return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button not pressed"
    return f"Interval: {n_intervals} - Button pressed"
```

As you can see, you reduce the number of functions and improve your performance, because in the first code you use 2 'if' statements, and in the second code you make an access to a list (with triggered_id you only make an access to a string).

However, Dash suggests that you create clear functions and don't create too many inputs and too many outputs in a single function. But sometimes there are special cases, like here (in my opinion).